# C++ Template specification for both const and regular type

Tags: c++, templates, specifications

I want to make a single template specification that will work for all form like:

```
char*, const char*, char* const
```

etc...

How do I do this with the C++ syntax?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: You are aware, that 'const char' is the same as 'char' except for the specification that you cannot alter the pointer any more, right? So technically you can just create your template with 'char *' and you're good.

Comment: @Taylor: Providing a version just for `char*` won't work because `char const*` doesn't convert to `char*`.

Comment: Yea but when i create a specialization of char*, and I pass const char* - the compiler goes to the regular template function.

Comment: Make a template for `T *` and add an `enable_if` on `remove_cv<T>` being equal to `char`.

Comment: @Kerrek, I would like to pass regular object not &object...

Comment: Do you really need templates here? How about const char* const?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need templates if you want to write a function which works with all three versions and does the same. Here is a sample program to demonstrate this:

```
void f(const char* const c)
{
}

int main()
{
  char ch='h';
  char*c=&ch;
  const char*cc="hi";
  char* const cc1=&ch;
  f(c);
  f(cc);
  f(cc1);
}
```

It compiles fine with g++4.7.